# Add Now() -1 in Column A When Adjacent Columns Have Data Added to It

Tags: vba, date

I'm updating a report everyday and adding data from yesterdays runs. I would like to insert a code in the macro to add the date into column A next to the newly added data without changing the previous dates already in column A.

```
Sub datedd()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        .Value = Now -1
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    End With
End Sub
```

But this changes all the dates in column A

not sure why pasting in the code breaks apart like this, sorry im new here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub datedd()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim firstRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    firstRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With Range("A" & CStr(firstRow) & ":A" & CStr(lastRow))
        .Value = Now -1
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    End With
End Sub
```